# Use https protocol for endpoints in Kubernetes Services

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks, kubernetes-service

Tried creating a Kubernetes endpoints service to invoke resource hosted outside the cluster via static IP's over HTTPS protocol.
Below is the endpoint code

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: serviceRequest
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8081
      targetPort: 8094      
      
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: serviceRequest
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: XX.XX.XX.XX // **external IP which is accessible as https://XX.XX.XX.XX:8094**
    ports:
      - port: 8094
```

But the above configuration is giving 400 Bad Request with message as "This combination of host and port requires TLS."

Same is working for http not for https exposed "ip".Could someone please guide how to achieve this.

##Update1
This is how the flow is configured.
[Ingress->service->endpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQkYT.png)

Comment: your endpoint doesn't contain the definitions for a TLS certificate. endpoint is rather crude, you're probably better off picking an ingress controller. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic)

Comment: @sleepyhead already have a ingress setup before my service layer and i dont want to expose the service public it is of clusterType and same goes for endpoints as well.

Could you please help with some more details on it. I am bit new to this concept. I have updated the flow in post.

Answer (score 1):

This is the error message your get when calling a `https` endpoint with `http`. Are you sure that whoever is calling your service, is calling it with *https://* at the beginning?

Comment: yes, with the configuration which i have mentioned above its making http://.

But my resource is on https://

Looking for a guidance how we can make a service to use https:// for external IP endpoints.

Comment: So, you want to call your service with http but have it forward that as https. I am afraid this is beyond k8s service functionality. You would need to use a service mesh like Isio for that: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-tls-origination/

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes Service is no more than a set of forwarding rules in `iptables` (most often), and it knows nothing about TLS.
If you want to enforce `https` redirection you might use ingress controller for this. All major ingress controllers have this capability.

For example, check for `nginx-ingress`.
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect.

Basically, all you need is to add this annotation to your ingress rule.
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"`

Answer (score 0):

Easypeasy, just add port 443 to the Service that will make the request TLS/https:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: serviceRequest
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 443 # <-- this is the way
      targetPort: 8094      
      
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: serviceRequest
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: XX.XX.XX.XX # **external IP which is accessible as https://XX.XX.XX.XX:8094**
    ports:
      - port: 8094
```

So you can reach your serviceRequest from your containers on https://serviceRequest url.

Also keep in mind that in yaml the # character is the comment sing not //